# How to change multiprocess to single process

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, multiprocess

Here is some code

How do I change the current multi-process part to a single process?

```
import multiprocessing

def process(self):
    if product != 0:
        if self.mlist.check(file_dictionary):
            self.mlist.patch(file_dictionary)
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.mlist.job, args = (file_dictionary, targ))
            self.multiprocess_list.append(process)
            process.start()

def wait(self):
    process_list = self.multiprocess_list
    for i in process_list:
        i.join(2)
```

Comment: Instead of `process = multiprocessing.Process(target = self.mlist.job, args = (file_dictionary, targ))`, just do `self.mlist.job(file_dictionary, targ)` to call the function directly.  However, now you will block until the function returns regardless of how long that takes.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please provide a minimal reproducible example like this:

```
import multiprocessing


def doSomething(k: str, v: int):
    print(f"key={k}, value={v}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
    processes = []
    for key, value in data.items():
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=doSomething, args=(key, value))
        processes.append(process)
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Now, replace the `import multiprocessing` by

```
class multiprocessing:  # Fake multiprocessing, not multiprocessing at all
    def __init__(self, target, args):
        self.target = target
        self.args = args

    @staticmethod
    def Process(target, args):
        return multiprocessing(target, args)

    def start(self):
        self.target(*self.args)

    def join(self):
        pass
```

The idea is that you provide the exact same interface (same names) but do not do multiprocessing. You can switch from and to multiprocessing easily.

- `multiprocessing` is no longer a library but a class
- `multiprocessing.Process` is no longer the constructor of a process object, but a static method
- `start()` just calls the method
- `join()` does nothing, since it ran synchronously already